Getting undefined characters in pieces section when trying to parse a .torrent file
Through various implementations on the net, I have implemented a Bendcode parser, and am trying to find the info hash of any input .torrent file. But, due to some problem, my parser gives correct output until the info dictionary (until number of pieces entry) after which I am getting undefined chars in the output. Please help me correct this error.
public class BencodeMine {

    String stringinput;
    int head = 0;
    int tail;
    byte[] input;

    public BencodeMine(String stringinput) throws IOException {
        this.stringinput = stringinput;
        tail = stringinput.length() - 1;
        ByteArrayOutputStream bOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream(12);
        bOutput.write(stringinput.getBytes());
        input = bOutput.toByteArray();
    }

    public Object parse() {

        byte head = read(input);
        if (head == 'i')
            return parseInt();
        else if (Character.isDigit(head))
            return parseString();
        else if (head == 'l')
            return parseList();
        else if (head == 'd')
            return parseDictionary();

        return "-2";
    }

    public byte read(byte[] input) {
        if (input[head] == 'i') {
            head++;
            //tail--;
            return 'i';
        } else if (Character.isDigit(input[head])) {
            return input[head];
        } else if (input[head] == 'l') {
            head++;
            //tail--;
            return 'l';
        } else if (input[head] == 'd') {
            head++;
            tail--;
            return 'd';
        } else return 'e';
    }

    public long parseInt() {
        long ans = 0;
        while (input[head] != 'e' && input[head] != ':') {
            ans *= 10;
            ans += (char)input[head] - '0';
            head++;
        }
        head++;
        return ans;
    }

    public String parseString() {
        long count = parseInt();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while(count!=0 && head<=tail){
            sb.append((char) input[head]);
            head++;
            count--;
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public ArrayList<Object> parseList(){
        ArrayList<Object> ans = new ArrayList<>();
        while(true){
            if(head > tail ) break;
            ans.add(parse());
            if(input[head]=='e') {
                head++;
                break;
            }
        }
        return ans;
    }

    public TreeMap<String,Object> parseDictionary(){
        TreeMap<String,Object> ans = new TreeMap<>();
        while(true){
            if(head>tail || input[head]=='e')
                    break;
            String key = parseString();
            ans.put(key, parse());
            if(input[head]=='e'){
                head++;
                break;
            }
        }
        return ans;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        FileReader fr = new FileReader("[New-raws] Pokémon (2023) - 51 [1080p] [AMZN].mkv.torrent");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String line = br.readLine() , whole_contents = "";
        while(line!=null) {
            whole_contents = whole_contents.concat(line);
            line = br.readLine();
        }
       
        BencodeMine parser = new BencodeMine(whole_contents);

        try {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("info.txt");

            TreeMap<String, Object> map = (TreeMap<String, Object>) parser.parse();
            fw.write(map.toString());
            String a = new String(String.valueOf(map));
            System.out.println(map);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error Occurred");
        }
    }
}

The output I am getting:
{announce=http://nyaa.tracker.wf:7777/announce, announce-list=[[http://nyaa.tracker.wf:7777/announce], [http://anidex.moe:6969/announce], [udp://tracker.coppersurfer.tk:6969/announce], [udp://tracker.opentrackr.org:1337/announce], [*udp://9.rarbg.to:2710/announce], [udp://9.rarbg.me:2710/announce], [udp://tracker.leechers-paradise.org:6969/announce], [udp://tracker.internetwarriors.net:1337/announce], [udp://tracker.cyberia.is:6969/announce], [udp://exodus.desync.com:6969/announce], [udp://tracker3.itzmx.com:6961/announce], [udp://tracker.torrent.eu.org:451/announce], [udp://tracker.tiny-vps.com:6969/announce], [udp://retracker.lanta-net.ru:2710/announce], [http://open.acgnxtracker.com:80/announce], [wss://tracker.openwebtorrent.com], [udp://open.stealth.si:80/announce]], comment=https://nyaa.si/view/1823558, created by=NyaaV2, creation date=1716553995, encoding=utf-8, info={length=571089672, name=[New-raws] Pokￃﾩmon (2023) - 51 [1080p] [AMZN].mkv, piece length=262144, pieces=@ ￈ﾒ￯﾿ﾽ￯﾿ﾽ9￯﾿ﾽQw￯﾿ﾽZS￯﾿ﾽ￯﾿ﾽ￯﾿ﾽ2Z￯﾿ﾽ￯﾿ﾽ5￯﾿ﾽ￯﾿ﾽ￯﾿ﾽ￯﾿ﾽ\￯﾿ﾽ￯﾿ﾽￍﾉ0￯﾿ﾽ~6￯﾿ﾽ￯﾿ﾽ￯﾿ﾽ^￯﾿ﾽ￯﾿ﾽ￯﾿ﾽp￯﾿ﾽ￯﾿ﾽ￯﾿ﾽ￯﾿ﾽ:<^,￯﾿ﾽ￯﾿ﾽv￯﾿ﾽQE6￯﾿ﾽ@K￯﾿ﾽ￯﾿ﾽ￯﾿ﾽ￯﾿ﾽ￯﾿ﾽ￯﾿ﾽ<￯﾿ﾽ￯﾿ﾽx￯﾿ﾽ￯﾿ﾽ￯﾿ﾽ￯﾿ﾽ￯﾿ﾽ￯﾿ﾽq￯﾿ﾽ>￯﾿ﾽ￯﾿ﾽ￯﾿ﾽ￯﾿ﾽ?￯﾿ﾽ￯﾿ﾽtX￯﾿ﾽb9qB)￯﾿ﾽ￯﾿ﾽ￯﾿ﾽ  ￯﾿ﾽs￯﾿ﾽ￦ﾇﾝ￯﾿ﾽ￯﾿ﾽf￯﾿ﾽrz￯﾿ﾽ￯﾿ﾽ￯﾿ﾽrbI￯﾿ﾽ' ￯﾿ﾽ￯﾿ﾽl￯﾿ﾽ￯﾿ﾽￂﾘM￯﾿ﾽk￯﾿ﾽD￯﾿ﾽw￯﾿ﾽ4 ￯﾿ﾽ'￯﾿ﾽCq3￯﾿ﾽ￯﾿ﾽ%3￯﾿ﾽ#￯﾿ﾽpￛﾆD(￯﾿ﾽￒﾧs￯﾿ﾽ￯﾿ﾽk￯﾿ﾽ￯﾿ﾽ%p￯﾿ﾽW￯﾿ﾽ￯﾿ﾽI￯﾿ﾽf￯﾿ﾽe￯﾿ﾽz_=￯﾿ﾽ/￯﾿ﾽ ￯﾿ﾽB￯﾿ﾽ￯﾿ﾽ+M[V￯﾿ﾽ!.￯﾿ﾽￏﾵ￯﾿ﾽ<}}

I tried taking input as a byte[], I know torrent files may not contain UTF-8 characters, so perhaps that might be the trouble, but if that is the problem then how do I convert the byte[] elements to UTF-8 chars again?
link to the file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jW3XC5xnYKEezGttSGLBHBJQcAOPOv4u/view?usp=drive_link

It's completely unclear how that code is being used, where it's getting its input from, etc

Plus, pieces are binary data (SHA1 hash codes) so can't be treated as strings

@g00se In my main class, I am passing a torrent file to the FileReader which is being read by BufferefReader after which I pass it to the BencodeMine's parse(). I will edit the question to include my main class as well.

@g00se are you referring to the (char) type conversion in parseString()?

FileReader fr = new FileReader("[New-raws] Pokémon (2023) - 51 [1080p] [AMZN].mkv.torrent"); is not going to fly for a start. A torrent file is a binary file. Readers are for text files. Can you post a link to that file?

@g00se Sure, I put the link in the description.  Oh I see, should I use a ByteArrayInputStream for that or something else?

Please provide a minimal reproducible example.
